# How to echo file with correct spaceline with Bash?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

hi i got bash file like this

```
#!/bin/bash
for y in $(aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --resource-type-filters eks --query "ResourceTagMappingList[*].{Project:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value,Project:Tags[?Key=='Project']|[0].Value}" --output text )
do
echo "$y" 
done
```

the real output if not use bash and for is

```
$aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --resource-type-filters eks --query "ResourceTagMappingList[*].{Project:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value,Project:Tags[?Key=='Project']|[0].Value}" --output text
Backend API
Test APi
```

but the output from bash file like this

```
Backend
API
Test
API
```

i need help to make output like this

```
Backend API
Test API
```

i try using sed and paste but not work please help me

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find a better duplicate. This is a common FAQ; see [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: Your loop iterates over the **words** resulting from the `aws` command, not over the lines.